# How to access files from project root folder in JUnit tests?

Tags: java, junit

**Problem:**

A method loads a file from a folder in the project root directory. When I use this method in JUnit, then the file isn't found because JUnit uses a different "context" to access files.

**Code:**

The method loading the file:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static String getSomeFile() throws Exception {
        Path path = Paths.get("somefiles/someFile");
        System.out.println(path.toAbsolutePath());
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(path));
    }
}
```

**>>** It correctly uses the path: `/[PATH_TO_PROJECT]/somefiles/someFile`

The test method:

```
@Test
public void getSomeFile() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(SomeClass.getSomeFile());
}
```

**>>** It tries to read the file from `/[PATH_TO_PROJECT]/.idea/modules/somefiles/someFile`

**Goal:**

Read the file via JUnit from the root folder, not `test/resources`.

**Constraints:**

- I don't want to load a copy from `test/resources` via `ClassLoader.getSystemResource("someFiles/someFile")`, because I would have to keep 2 versions of the file. This is too risky.
- I don't want to use the absolute path to access the file, because environment can change.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: To whom it may concern: My temporary solution is to load the file via its absolute path retrieved via `Lightbend Config`. Not a beautiful solution, but changing a config file once in a while is also not that bad.

Comment: Please explain why following the standard provided by Maven and the good practices is too risky. Maybe you made some things more complex than they should.

Comment: @davidxxx These files are meant as specifications for reading CSV files which are automatically retrieved from a third party. So they need extensive testing and if I would ever forget to keep both versions in sync then it would cause a lot of headaches.